# iOS 5: UITableView cells are not scrolling smooth

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Using:

- iOS 5, ARC, StoryBoards.

Have 1 image and text on every cell. Images are not getting resized while scrolling. Have two versions of images image.png and image@2x.png.

The custom cell was managed by drugging UIImageView and UILabel in storyboard.

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
Continent *continent=[self.items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
ContinentCell *cell = (ContinentCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.continentName.text=continent.continentName;
    cell.textView.text=continent.countriesHash;
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:continent.continentImage ofType:@"png"]];
 return cell;
}
```

Where's the evil? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks fine, how many cells are you showing onscreen and how big is the image file?

Comment: Try using Time Profiler in Instruments to see where most of the processing time is occurring in your app.  This should help narrow the optimisation possibilities.  That being said, how big are your images? Are they being scaled?

Comment: well, first thing you should worry about: you're not initialising any cell. After the dequeuing, you should check if the cell == nil and, if so, initialize it.

Comment: "Images are not getting resized while scrolling." 42 X 35

Comment: @Bruno Koga Input an normal answer with the code snippet. If it will help I'll be able to accept your answer.

Comment: @Bruno Koga - This is not required under iOS5 using Storyboards.  A cell is guaranteed to be non-nil when using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.  See a previous answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11042129/558933

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:continent.continentImage ofType:@"png"]];
```

Is expensive. You want to load the image the image asynchronously in the background then present it on the main thread when ready.

Here's a very rough solution

```
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:continent.continentImage ofType:@"png"]];
      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = img;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Well, there's no problem with images. The cell trembles himself while scrolling. I faced the same issue not a long time ago, and I really thought that the problem was the automatic image resize. But it wasn't. The problem is that cell just trembles while scrolling.

Comment: Are you using transparencies or shadows?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Polishing your App: Tips and Tricks to Improve Responsiveness and Performance video of WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=105) from **26:48**. They have discussed exactly about the problem you are facing. Don't miss out, it would be really helpful..!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your images are not big and then:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Continent *continent=[self.items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    ContinentCell *cell = (ContinentCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) cell = [[ContinentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
    cell.continentName.text = continent.continentName;
    cell.textView.text = continent.countriesHash;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:continent.continentImage];
    return cell;
}
```

I made 2 significant changes:

1. Added `if(cell == nil) [[ContinentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]`, because I didn't find the code for initializing cell (unless you use `-registerNib` or the other super-sectet function, which I can't say because it's under NDA)
2. Replaced `imageWithContentsOfFile:...` with simple `imageNamed`, because you load the image from your main bundle and, if image is not big, `-imageNamed` caches it, so it loads quicker. (and -imageNamed doesn't need the file extension)

Comment: No. 1 is wrong as under iOS5 and storyboards dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is guaranteed to be non-nil.  See more here in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11042129/558933

Comment: OK, so maybe the second one will help?

Comment: Are you sure that -imageNamed is better than imageWithContentsOfFile:?

Comment: With smaller images -- yes (it was told on one of WWDC '11 or '10 sessions)

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                                 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Continent *continent=[self.items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    ContinentCell *cell = (ContinentCell*)[tableView 
                               dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[ContinentCell alloc] 
                               initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                               reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }
    cell.continentName.text=continent.continentName;
    cell.textView.text=continent.countriesHash;
    //cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                        pathForResource:continent.continentImage ofType:@"png"]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage cachedImage:continent.continentImage];
    return cell;
}
```

I will recommend you to use imageNamed instead of imageWithContentsOfFile.

**imageNamed** method loads the image in **cache** and next time it will load from cache, where as imageWithContentsOfFile method loads the image from your specified path without `NO` cahching and it will create multiple copy in memory.

You can create your own image cache method. Just declare NSMutableDictionary *imagedCacheDict

**If you run out of memory you can remove all the objects by** 
[imagedCacheDict removeAllObjects]

```
 - (UIImage*)cachedImage:(NSString*)fileName
{
   UIImage *cacheImage = [imagedCacheDict objectForKey:fileName];

   if (nil == cacheImage)
   {
      NSString *cacheImageFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", 
                                   [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], fileName];
      cacheImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:cacheImageFile];
      [imagedCacheDict setObject:cacheImage forKey:fileName];
   }
   return cacheImage;
}
```

So, never use the imageNamed method, it will bring out your application by consuming lot of memory.

Comment: Not this again.  Nathan has made it clear he is using iOS5 and Storyboards.  Under iOS5 and storyboards dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is guaranteed to be non-nil and so the whole if (cell == nil) code is unnecessary.  See more here in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11042129/558933

Comment: Please explain me more about this string stringWithFormat:@"%@/thumbnails/%@.png"